# Iterate through a list and create a html element for every item in the list?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Model(Objectives) which stores the data I want to iterate through.

Here is its code in the models.py

```
class Objectives(models.Model):
    target = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    time_left= models.DateField()
    gamemodes= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my View.py for it.

```
"""@login_required"""
def user_obj(request):
    user_obj= Objectives.objects.filter(gamemodes__username="test1")
    print("__________________________________________________________")
    print(user_obj)  # Add this line for debugging
    return render(request, 'user_obj.html', {'user_obj': user_obj})
```

and here is the html I have to iterate through the list:

```
   <div class="Q3" >
    {% for ab in user_obj%}
      <div class="task-item">
        <h3>{{ ab.target }}</h3>
        <p>{{ ab.description }}</p>
        <p>Due Date: {{ ab.time_left|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Essentially I need it to create a task-item for every objective, I have 4 objectives on the computer for testing so there is something to test on.

I also have a user_obj.html file which has essentially the same code as the html code above.

In the urlpatterns of url.py I have the following:

```
path('user_obj/', user_obj, name='user_obj'),
```

Please note that this is the last element of the urlpatterns so maybe there should not be a comma at the end.

user_obj.html

```
<html>
<body>
    {% for task in user_tasks %}
        <div class="task-item">
            <h3>{{ task.name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ task.description }}</p>
            <p>Due Date: {{ task.due_date|date:"F j, Y" }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

the following code in the shell :

```
user_tasks = Objectives.objects.filter(gamemodes__username="@test1")
>>> for i in user_tasks:
...     print(i.gamemodes)
... 
@test1
@test1
@test1
@test1
>>>
```

Comment: To iterate through the `Objectives` you need to replace your query `Task.objects.filter(gamemodes=request.user)` with `Objectives.objects.filter(gamemodes=request.user)`. If this is not what you want please give us more code and details.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick and I have added and updated the code

Comment: But your path refers to `user_tasks`, not `user_obj`?

Comment: I have tried that and still no effort, i have updated it even more and added the exact .html file as well as some debugging information

Comment: @johntruman: `{% for task in user_obj %}`. While you can obfuscate code, please obfuscate in a *bijective* manner, ensure that the same name as input remains the same as output and vice versa.

Comment: I have made some headway on displaying it but there is still some problems, I agree with you, the code has started to become too confusing as the problem has now essentially shifted, I think its best to delete this question, it offers no insight

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please *remove* the trailing space in the context, this will only generate trouble. Although less of a problem, filenames with spaces are not a good idea either:

```
@login_required
def user_obj(request):
    modes_avalable = Task.objects.filter(gamemodes=request.user)
    return render(
        request,
        'modes_avalable.html',  # 🖘 no space
        #                🖟 no space
        {'modes_available': modes_avalable},
    )
```

since you pass the `QuerySet` as `modes_available` (there was a typo in the name of the context as well), you enumerate over this with:

```
{% for ab in modes_available %}
  <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got rid of the space in the user_obj function yet there is no change, the code still does not work. Neither print statement isn't activated. What else can I try?

Comment: @johntruman: so where did you register the view? Can you share the `urls`? Please edit the question.

Comment: I have edited the question to also now show my urlpatterns array from url.py